# How to search for peripheral bluetooth devices, on iOS using objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, arduino

Should I have the app search for devices and then connect or have the app search for devices that are already connected, and how would I go about doing this? Since I am new to Xcode and app development. I am trying to build an app to connect to a bluetooth shield on an Arduino chip. Thank you in advance for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

This link have detail step by step

http://www.raywenderlich.com/85900/arduino-tutorial-integrating-bluetooth-le-ios-swift